# How to convince a Java Constructor to accept a List containing objects whose Class implements a certain Interface

Tags: java, list, constructor, interface

I am currently implementing a few changes to a software application which makes heavy use of the delegation design pattern. I would therefore like to write my code accordingly. Currently though I can't seem to find my way around an issue that has kept me busy for a good while.

My current task is to create some kind of generic "operation class" which will be used by all objects that implement a certain interface to perform actions on those objects. In order to achieve this, the processing class will instantiate an object of this operation class for any object that needs to be changed and perform its changes through the object of this operation class.

*My issue is that I am not able to instantiate "operation class" objects using a constructor that accepts a list of objects whose classes implement a certain interface*.

The constructor of the "operation class" looks like this (please find a complete code example below):

```
public OperationClass(List<InterfaceName> listOfObjects) {
    super();
    listedObjects = listOfObjects;
}
```

It will be called like this:

```
operationObject = new OperationClass(object.getSubObjectsList());
```

Eclipse will complain like

```
"The constructor OperationClass(List<SubObjects>) is undefined."
```

That seems a little strange to me as the Class that delivers the List implements the Interface that is mentioned in the Constructor's definition. Interestingly, using a constructor that will accept a single object of this class will work just fine.
My questions are:

1. Is it even possible to work with constructors accepting Lists of Interfaces?
2. How do I make my code work without losing my ability to use the code for all classes implementing the interface?

**Note:** Edited the code thanks to your feedback. The trick was to change the list's datatype to the Interface type and to ensure that the Getter method is changed accordingly.

---

***Complete code example***

**Interface**

```
package test02_interfaceList;

import java.util.List;

public interface PersonI {

    public abstract String getFirstName();

    public abstract void setFirstName(String firstName);

    public abstract String getLastName();

    public abstract void setLastName(String lastName);

    public abstract List<PersonI> getSiblings();

    public abstract void setSiblings(List<PersonI> siblings);

}
```

**Class implementing the Interface**

```
package test02_interfaceList;

import java.util.List;

public class Member implements PersonI {

    private int memberId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<PersonI> siblings;

    public int getMemberId() {
        return memberId;
    }

    public void setMemberId(int memberId) {
        this.memberId = memberId;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see test02_interfaceList.PersonI#getFirstName()
     */
    @Override
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see test02_interfaceList.PersonI#setFirstName(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see test02_interfaceList.PersonI#getLastName()
     */
    @Override
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see test02_interfaceList.PersonI#setLastName(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see test02_interfaceList.PersonI#getSiblings()
     */
    @Override
    public List<PersonI> getSiblings() {
        return siblings;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSiblings(List<PersonI> siblings) {
        this.siblings = siblings;

    }
}
```

**Generic "operations" class**

```
package test02_interfaceList;

import java.util.List;

public class Delegate {

    private Member currentMember;
    private List<PersonI> associatedPeople;
    private PersonI associatedPerson;

    /**
     * Standard Constructor, takes list of objects which implements the PersonI
     * interface.
     * 
     * @param listOfPeople
     */
    public Delegate(List<PersonI> listOfPeople) {
        super();
        associatedPeople = listOfPeople;
    }

    /**
     * Alternative Constructor, takes one object implementing the PersonI
     * interface.
     * 
     * @param listOfPeople
     */
    public Delegate(PersonI person) {
        super();
        associatedPerson = person;
    }

    public void addToAssocPeopleList(PersonI person) {
        System.out.println("Adding " + person.getFirstName() + " to list of associated people.");
        associatedPeople.add(person);
    }

    public void removeFromAssocPeopleList(PersonI person) {
        System.out.println("Removing " + person.getFirstName() + " from list of associated people.");
        associatedPeople.remove(person);
    }

    public Member getCurrentMember() {
        return currentMember;
    }

    public void setCurrentMember(Member currentMember) {
        this.currentMember = currentMember;
    }

    public List<PersonI> getAssociatedPeople() {
        return associatedPeople;
    }

    public void setAssociatedPeople(List<PersonI> associatedPeople) {
        this.associatedPeople = associatedPeople;
    }

    public PersonI getAssociatedPerson() {
        return associatedPerson;
    }

    public void setAssociatedPerson(PersonI associatedPerson) {
        this.associatedPerson = associatedPerson;
    }

}
```

**Class with main() Method**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Main Method

        Delegate member01Operations;
        List<PersonI> siblings = new ArrayList<PersonI>();

        Member member01 = new Member();
        member01.setMemberId(42);
        member01.setFirstName("John");
        member01.setLastName("Doe");
        member01.setSiblings(siblings);

        Member member02 = new Member();
        member02.setMemberId(43);
        member02.setFirstName("Joanna");
        member02.setLastName("Doe");

        Member member03 = new Member();
        member03.setMemberId(43);
        member03.setFirstName("James");
        member03.setLastName("Doe");

        // The constructor now accepts the returned list as it contains the
        // PersonI interface datatype
        member01Operations = new Delegate(member01.getSiblings());

        member01Operations.addToAssocPeopleList(member02);
        member01Operations.addToAssocPeopleList(member03);

        for (PersonI person : member01Operations.getAssociatedPeople()) {
            System.out.println(person.getFirstName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post only the relevant code? Also, what is the problem with passing List<T> as parameter to the constructor?

Comment: Note that in Java generics are *not* covariant

Comment: @WeareBorg, I think List<T> wont guarantee the same Interface.

Comment: Oh, okay, yes, I didn't read it throughly, then you have to pass the interface name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should understand that `List<SubObjects>` is not a sub-class of `List<InterfaceName>`, so you can't pass a `List<SubObjects>` where a `List<InterfaceName>` is expected.

You should change `getSubObjectsList()` to return a `List<InterfaceName>` instead of `List<SubObjects>`. It's usually preferable to use interface types instead of class types in variables and method arguments anyway.

Comment: The reason for this can be demonstrated by picturing what would happen if you passed in a `List<SubObjects>`, and the constructor then tried to add an instance of `InterfaceName` to the structure. (Of course not *knowing* that the List was parameterized with `SubObjects`.) What would happen? For this reason, the compiler requires the behavior @Eran describes.

Comment: Should be: "You should change ``getSubObjectsList()`` to return a ``List<? extends InterfaceName>``." And I'd say, consume abstract arguments (by interface) but ``return`` a specific value (by the implementing class).

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the code .Please try to use like below.

```
package test02_interfaceList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Delegate {

    private Member currentMember;
    private List<PersonI<?>> associatedPeople = new ArrayList<PersonI<?>>();
    private PersonI<?> associatedPerson;

    /**
     * Standard Constructor, takes list of objects which implements the PersonI
     * interface.
     * 
     * @param listOfPeople
     */
    public Delegate(List<? extends PersonI<?>> listOfPeople) {
        super();
        for (PersonI<?> personI : listOfPeople) {
            associatedPeople.add(personI);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Alternative Constructor, takes one object implementing the PersonI
     * interface.
     * 
     * @param listOfPeople
     */
    public Delegate(PersonI<?> person) {
        super();
        associatedPerson = person;
    }

    public void addToAssocPeopleList(PersonI<?> person) {
        System.out.println("Adding " + person.getFirstName() + " to list of associated people.");
        associatedPeople.add(person);
    }

    public void removeFromAssocPeopleList(PersonI<?> person) {
        System.out.println("Removing " + person.getFirstName() + " from list of associated people.");
        associatedPeople.remove(person);
    }

    public Member getCurrentMember() {
        return currentMember;
    }

    public void setCurrentMember(Member currentMember) {
        this.currentMember = currentMember;
    }

    public List<? extends PersonI<?>> getAssociatedPeople() {
        return associatedPeople;
    }

    public void setAssociatedPeople(List<PersonI<?>> associatedPeople) {
        this.associatedPeople = associatedPeople;
    }

    public PersonI<?> getAssociatedPerson() {
        return associatedPerson;
    }

    public void setAssociatedPerson(PersonI<?> associatedPerson) {
        this.associatedPerson = associatedPerson;
    }

}
```

Member class :

```
package test02_interfaceList;

import java.util.List;

public class Member implements PersonI<Member> {

    private int memberId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Member> siblings;

    public int getMemberId() {
        return memberId;
    }

    public void setMemberId(int memberId) {
        this.memberId = memberId;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see test02_interfaceList.PersonI#getFirstName()
     */
    @Override
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see test02_interfaceList.PersonI#setFirstName(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see test02_interfaceList.PersonI#getLastName()
     */
    @Override
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see test02_interfaceList.PersonI#setLastName(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see test02_interfaceList.PersonI#getSiblings()
     */
    @Override
    public List<Member> getSiblings() {
        return siblings;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see test02_interfaceList.PersonI#setSiblings(java.util.List)
     */
    @Override
    public void setSiblings(List<Member> siblings) {
        this.siblings = siblings;
    }

}
```

Person Interface :

```
package test02_interfaceList;

import java.util.List;

public interface PersonI<T extends PersonI> {

    public abstract String getFirstName();

    public abstract void setFirstName(String firstName);

    public abstract String getLastName();

    public abstract void setLastName(String lastName);

    public abstract List<T> getSiblings();

    public abstract void setSiblings(List<T> siblings);

}
```

Main Class :

```
package test02_interfaceList;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Main Method

            Delegate peopleOperations;

            Member member01 = new Member();
            member01.setMemberId(42);
            member01.setFirstName("John");
            member01.setLastName("Doe");

            Member member02 = new Member();
            member01.setMemberId(43);
            member01.setFirstName("Joanna");
            member01.setLastName("Doe");

            member01.getSiblings().add(member02);
            member02.getSiblings().add(member01);

            // This works
            peopleOperations = new Delegate(member01);

            // This doesn't ('Constructor(List<Member>) undefined') - why? Class
            // Member implements the PersonI interface!
            peopleOperations = new Delegate(member01.getSiblings());

        }

    }
```